# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com/mysql/jdbc/Driver" with sql driver in pom

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, intellij-idea

EDIT: Fixed the issue - I wasn't declaring the dependency within the apache tomcat plugin:

```
<extraDependencies>
                                <extraDependency>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                                    <version>10.1.3.1</version>
                                </extraDependency>
                                <extraDependency>
                                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.4</version>
                                </extraDependency>
                                <extraDependency>
                                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                                    <version>5.1.38</version>
                                </extraDependency>
                            </extraDependencies>
```

As well as being declared in the pom as seen below.

---

Question:

I'm trying to use the mysql jdbc driver in my maven project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

But i'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com/mysql/jdbc/Driver";
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.ollynural.app.database.retrievedatabase.DatabaseAccessor.returnSummonerDTOFromDatabaseUsingName(DatabaseAccessor.java:53)
```

EDIT: Tried using the string instead of CLASS, and error is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And DatabaseAccessor returnSummonerDTOFromDatabaseUsingName is:

```
    String URL = prop.getProperty("URL");
    String USER = prop.getProperty("USER");
    String PASS = prop.getProperty("PASS");
    String CLASS = prop.getProperty("CLASS");
    String TABLE_UNIVERSITY_INFO =     prop.getProperty("TABLE_BASIC_INFO");
    try {
        Class.forName(CLASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find SQL Driver");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The properties are:

```
URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/league_database_schema";
USER="username";
PASS="password"
CLASS="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

The properties are getting to the class fine, but I have no idea why it can't find the class. I'm relatively new to maven, and this was working before i moved over to intellij and eclipse, but any help would be incredibly helpful!

Thank you

Comment: Can you please try `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`? Looks rather strange, that the exception shows the full qualified name with slash. And can you use other libraries, which are added using maven? Just to be sure, that Maven and your build path are configured correctly.

Comment: Yes I can use other libraries fine, I think you may have a point i'll try that now :)

Comment: Tried above, and now am getting 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' So not the problem unfortunately

Comment: How are you launching this thing?

Comment: Running using: mvn tomcat7:run and doing mvn clean compile package and install before

Comment: When I get home from internship I will check the war it's building into, and check if the driver is in the lib folder. This was suggested by a colleague - if it isn't there maybe I can put it in the lib folder directly

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend checking the repository to see if the jar file has actually been installed.

Within the repository, you should find it in: `(repository name)/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/`

There should be a jar file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar`
and a pom file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.pom`

I believe that should be it for the repository, if anyone has more ideas/corrections please share. Thanks.

Comment: Have checked yesterday, it is there - I also deleted all the repository files and then got Maven to redownload the driver and other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell by the fragment you posted, but is your dependency declared in the **dependencies** section of your pom, and not in **dependencyManagement**?

Comment: I'm quite new to working with a pom, I'm looking at: [this link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) about it, but could you explain what it is/why it is needed? I will try putting it in a dependencyManagement tag